# Count number of row using mysql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I trying to use Laravel `count()` function to get the count of row. I have below code to count the number of row of 2 join table.

Example 1:

```
$row = DB::table('log_user_login')
                ->select(DB::raw('log_user_login.Password as LogPassword'), 'user.*')
                ->join('user', 'log_user_login.Username', '=', 'user.Username')
                ->where('log_user_login.LoginSession', '!=', '')
                ->groupBy('user.ID')
                ->get();
$count = sizeof($row);
```

Example 2:

```
$count = DB::table('log_user_login')
            ->select(DB::raw('log_user_login.Password as LogPassword'), 'user.*')
            ->join('user', 'log_user_login.Username', '=', 'user.Username')
            ->where('log_user_login.LoginSession', '!=', '')
            ->groupBy('user.ID')
            ->count();
```

When I `echo $count` form Example 1, the number of `$count` is 15415. But `$count` of Example 2 return me 89. May I know why this happen and how can I get the number of row without using the `get()`?

Answer (score 3):

Example 1 displays the sizeof array in bytes, but example 2 displays total count returned by table.

So, best way to get total count is using ->count() as done in example 2.

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try it.
$row = DB::table('log_user_login')
                ->select(DB::raw('log_user_login.Password as LogPassword'), 'user.*')
                ->join('user', 'log_user_login.Username', '=', 'user.Username')
                ->where('log_user_login.LoginSession', '!=', '')
                ->groupBy('user.ID')
                ->get();
echo $count = count($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use sizeof(). So many time its return amount of memory allocated.

**Use count() instead of sizeof().**